# How would I display different headers in Rails in application.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

How would I display different versions of headers in Rails in my application.html.erb view? For instance, for my landing page, I have a pretty big header that includes a callout and some sign-up and sign-in buttons. For other static pages, I have a normal small header with a logo and a few links to the right. And for my dashboard when users log in, it will look a little different as well.

How can I display certain headers in an if/else statement where Rails will output the different versions of headers based on the current url or view in my application.html.erb?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question with an example this is what you may want to do.
Rails has a provision to use nested view templates using the `content_for` and `yield` tags.
Do the following thing to achieve what you want -

1. In `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` - Add a ternary expression which acts as a `if else`. While rendering the views rails will look for a `<% content_for :custom_header do %>` in the view templates. If it doesn't find that it will render the partial `app/views/layouts/_default_header.html.erb` instead.

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
     <title><%= @page_title or "Page Title" %></title>
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
   </head>
   <body>
     <!-- Code to conditionally load a header -->
     <%= content_for?(:custom_header) ? yield(:custom_header) : render :partial => "layouts/default_header" %></div>

     <!-- For the body -->
     <%= yield %>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. Now since you say that most pages will have a static small header, save the html code for that in a partial under `app/views/layouts/_default_header.html.erb`.
3. In you landing page (for example the the view `app/views/welcome/index.html.erb`) you can use the `content_for` tag with the identifier `:custom_header` that we have used in the `application.html.erb`
   Add the following in your landing page.

   ```
   <% content_for :custom_header do %>
     <div class="custom-header">
       <!-- Your complex header with sign in and signup links... -->
     </div>
   <% end %>
   ```

The ternary operator in the `application.html.erb` will pick up this content from the content_for tag in the landing page and insert the content in place of the `yield(:custom_header)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a nice solution. I ran into a problem with

```<%= content_for?(:custom_header) ? yield(:custom_header) : render :partial => "layouts/default_header" %></div>```

I had to use parenthesis with my `render` method. For example:

```<%= content_for?(:custom_header) ? yield(:custom_header) : render(partial: "layouts/default_header") %></div>```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may want to use a [nested layout](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts).